# SQL Plus show first four and last 4 numbers in the output

Tags: sql, sqlplus, substr

How can I select a columns first 4 digits and last 4 digits and use an "X" placement for all the numbers in between?

Example

> SELECT id from users where user_name ='Tom';

```
Output
5958694850384567
```

I am trying to get only the first and last 4 numbers with x's as placements to any number that is being masked:

Trying to get it to look like

```
Output:5958XXXXXXXX4567
```

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(id, 1, 4) from users
where user_name ='Tom'
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply use the [`LEFT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql) and [`RIGHT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql) functions? These will give you a specific number of characters from the left or right of a given string respectively.

You can also combine those to build your complete string using the [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(id, 4), 'XXXXXXXX', RIGHT(id, 4))
  FROM users
 WHERE user_name = 'Tom'
```

Additionally, if you don't always have a given number of characters within the string, you could calculate the middle section of your output as well via the [`REPLICATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql) function and a bit of math:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(id, 4), REPLICATE('X', LEN(id) - 8), RIGHT(id, 4))
  FROM users
 WHERE user_name = 'Tom'
```

**Oracle Version**

I didn't realize that you were using Oracle specifically and assumed SQL Server, so I'll provide some similar code to handle this in that flavor:

```
SELECT LEFT(id, 4) || RPAD('X', LEN(id) - 8, 'X') || RIGHT(id, 4)
  FROM users
 WHERE user_name = 'Tom'
```

Comment: Thanks @RION  ! I get the following error when trying to use concate ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Comment: Based on that error, it looks like you are using Oracle and not SQL Server. I've added an example, which may work in your environment. If not, let me know and I'll adjust it further.